# PyAudio: stream.write() only plays 1/4th the length it should

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have here a class for a pyAudio streamer that plays can play multiple sounds of singular frequency in succession.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

class SingleFrequencyPlayer:
    def __init__(self, fs=44100):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.samples=np.ones((0), dtype=np.float32)
        self.log=[]
        self.fs=fs #fs: sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
        
    def add_samples(self, volume, duration, f):
        #volume: range [0.0, 1.0]
        #duration: in seconds, may be float
        #f: sine frequency, Hz, may be float
        
        # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
        samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(self.fs*duration)*f/self.fs)).astype(np.float32)
        self.samples=np.append(self.samples,samples*volume)
        self.log+=[[volume, duration, f]]
    
    def play_sound(self):
        # for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
        stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                        channels=1,
                        rate=self.fs,
                        output=True)
        # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
        stream.write(self.samples)

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
```

However, I am having a problem. **The sound that is emitted from stream.write() has only 1/4th its given duration.** However, it still plays the correct duration of the different sounds given.

For example, if I tell it to play 5 seconds of 500Hz, it would only play for 1.25 seconds, or 5/4 seconds. If I instead, tell it to play 5 seconds of 500Hz, then 75 seconds of 900Hz, it would proceed to correctly play the first 5 seconds in 500Hz, then only play 15 seconds of 900Hz, for a total of 20 seconds out of the original 80.

I am not sure why this is happening. I assume it is because of the format of pyaudio.paFloat32 that I am using, that reads 4 bytes at a time. But if I make it use a format that reads 1 byte at a time, the sound is incorrect. Also, the array I am writing onto the stream has the correct format (np.float32). So, I am unsure of how to proceed. My current fix is to add in 3 times the length of the sample into it, so that it would not be played anyway. But obviously, we should fix bugs, not work around them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your log contain the expected number of samples (given the sample frequency/duration you're using)?

Comment: One example of the use of numpy arrays with pyaudio I found used `stream.write(samples.astype(np.float32).tostring())` - in other words, an explicit conversion to bytes before calling `.write()`.

Comment: @jasonharper it works! it says ```.tostring()``` is deprecated and to use ```.tobytes()``` instead, but it works! Thank you!